# How do I add entries to existing list in Client Server java application?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java. I am asked to develop an online multiplayer game using java.

On first JFrame ,Player has to put user id. When the player clicks the login button I need to put his/her name in a list. After another one login with a user id , I need to put his/her user id for the existing list(After the first one). What I tried is this. But when I run multiple applications , the name is only added in separate applications. The second name is not adding after the first one. How can I overcome this issue? Please help me.

```
public class Players {
private static Client client;

//Getting details from Fist Form.

  public Players(String name, String address, int port) {
  client= new Client(name,address,port);
            String b = client.getName();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"name :" + b);

      // create map to store
      Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

     // create list one and store values
     List<String> valSetOne = new ArrayList<String>();
    valSetOne.add(b);
     map.put("A", valSetOne);

     for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<String> values = entry.getValue();
                System.out.println("Players = " + values);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

}}
```

Thanks

Comment: um ... these two sentences : *"I'm a beginner in Java"* and *"I am asked to develop an online multiplayer game using java"* ... they're mutually exclusive. Sorry, its just like that. You **could** write something network-based which displays a few rectangles and circles but ... thats pretty much about it, you wont develop an actual game.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the mistake here :) I didn't get you what you mean exactly @specializt

Comment: ... what? Which mistake? I think you should start with programming basics instead - this is an extremely advanced topic ... its like trying to invent cold fusion technology without any knowledge about physics. Your teacher is trying to turn you into ridicule, apparently. Focus on your actual tasks / homework and ... forget about games for now, **one step at a time**

Comment: The answer is in the question title: *client **server***. If something must be shared across different programs, it must be held in a server, and the clients send requests and updates to the server.